# How do I set the exposure manually on a Nikon D5100?

Tags: nikon, exposure, light

I bought a year ago a Nikon D5100, but there is still one thing I don't know about it : how do I set my exposure manually? I can set it with the AE button, but is there a way to set it manually, I mean without pointing the camera to a light, press AE and pray for the exposure to be okay?
Thanks answering me.

Comment: what does the manual of the camera say about this?

Answer (score 2):

To use Manual mode, select M for manual, then use the command dial to select shutter speed and press the "aperture/exposure compensation" button to select the aperture. Adjust the shutter speed or aperture so that the exposure indicator is centered and gives you optimum exposure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the mode dial button, set it to "S" (Shutter priority) and then set your exposure value, or set it to "M" and set both the exposure and aperture.
 [image: Mode dial]

Image source: [Nikon D5100 For Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/nikon-d5100-for-dummies-cheat-sheet.html)